# Python Netmiko Timout issue

Tags: python-3.x, cisco-ios, netmiko

Having issues with Netmiko,  Trying to retreive output of this command
'show inventory | include Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR'
I get good results with all devices includeing cisco 4016 single chassis devices.
The problem I have is with a Cisco 4016 multi-chassis device it seems to time out when I send the show inventory command.   It always returns a socket error

#####Config
modules = net_connect.send_command('show inventory | include Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR',delay_factor=2)
print('the type is: ',type(modules))
print(modules)

I've tried with and without delay factor,  also send_command_timing

if I enter the command directly from ssh, it takes 13 seconds to execute.

####################################################################
netmiko log

DEBUG:netmiko:[find_prompt()]: prompt is RP/0/RP0:Cisco4016MC_Hostname#
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
RP/0/RP0:WPBHFLJU-X64Y34A#
DEBUG:netmiko:Clear buffer detects data in the channel
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:write_channel: b'show inventory | include Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR\n'
DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern is: show\ inventory\ |\ include\ Cisco\ 100G\ QSFP28\ LR
DEBUG:netmiko:_read_channel_expect read_data: show inventory | include Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR

DEBUG:netmiko:Pattern found: show\ inventory\ |\ include\ Cisco\ 100G\ QSFP28\ LR show inventory | include Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR

DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: Fri Sep 17 17:54:43.593 UTC

DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: NAME: "Optics0/1/0/0", DESCR: "Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR Pluggable Optics Module"
NAME: "Optics0/8/0/0", DESCR: "Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR Pluggable Optics Module"

DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: NAME: "Optics1/4/0/5", DESCR: "Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR Pluggable Optics Module"
NAME: "Optics1/4/0/6", DESCR: "Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR Pluggable Optics Module"

DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel: NAME: "Optics1/7/0/0", DESCR: "Cisco 100G QSFP28 LR Pluggable Optics Module"

DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:netmiko:read_channel:
DEBUG:paramiko.transport:starting thread (client mode): 0xf706358

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

As another option you can try to get this information with paramiko. If the output gives you a too big data, you can get the outputs part by part, and save it into a file.
So that you can parse your data as you wish. Please see an example:

```
remote_connection.send("show inventory " + " \r")
time.sleep(2)
output3 = remote_connection.recv(99999999)
result3 = output3.decode('ascii').strip("\n")

LOGfile = "log_show_inventory.txt" 
log = open(LOGfile, 'a')
log.write(result3)
log.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, the `CiscoBaseConnection` in Netmiko sets `fast_cli` default value to `True`, which simply multiples `delay_factor` value by `0.1`. So, a default delay factor of 1 (100 seconds) will be 10 seconds only (100 * 0.1 = 10).

To avoid this behavior, just set `fast_cli` to `False`. Doing so will give the command the full duration (100 seconds) to collect the show command.

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "x.x.x.x",
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "secret": "",
    "fast_cli": False,  # this item
    "global_delay_factor": 2,  # optional in case it takes more than 100 seconds
}

with ConnectHandler(**device) as conn:
    modules = conn.send_command(command_string="show inventory")

print(modules)
```